# Would you like Archaeology.SE?

Tags: discussion

Some questions here are aimed at times or events known only or mostly from archaeological evidence, and some frowned upon asking such questions here. Now there is no good alternative so it's completely OK, but wouldn't it be nice to have Archaeology.SE as an alternative for such questions?

[Here is the Archaeology proposal on Area51.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61388/archaeology)

EDIT: the Archaeology proposal was restarted. Now it's even longer from reaching beta, but if the proposal attracts few experts (as well as many others), it can make it in the end.

Comment: The proposal's example questions (so far) have nothing to do with History.SE. That's a good thing, the overlap doesn't seem as significant as I thought when I first read your question. Seems like an interesting proposal, good luck!

Comment: What we really seem to need is neither History.SE nor Archaeology.SE, but Anthropology.SE.

Comment: @choster: there is [Athropology.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49575/anthropology?referrer=GVjrksEQ_KrIxr8VY2IctQ2) proposal too.

Comment: Could you please link to the new (non-deleted) proposal, if there is one? Thanks!

Comment: @nic - currently there's none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like it, just because it would remove a lot of questions from here that we currently allow because there is no Archeology site for them to go to. However, I doubt I'd participate in it myself.

There would be a fair amount of overlap though. If nothing else, were such a stack to come into existence, we'd probably end up spending a lot of time migrating questions back and forth. A lot of times people come here and ask what they honestly think are history questions that end up having archeology answers. For example: [Which is the first genocide?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/which-is-the-first-genocide/7319#7319)

Also, many questions about the [bronze-age](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bronze-age) cannot be properly answered without using a mix of both History and Archeology (and sometimes Linguistics).

So personally, I'd also be OK with it never making, and us keeping [bronze-age](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bronze-age), and [pre-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-history) to ourselves.

Comment: "For example: Which is the first genocide?" *touché*

Comment: @astabada - No discredit intended. It happens rather a lot. That was just the first example I found when looking for one.

Comment: No problem whatsoever, just being sociable :)